# How can I better optimise my memory usage with the following code?

Tags: python, performance, memory, hashmap, hashtable

So this is a problem from leetcode. I am given two strings s and t.
String t is generated by random shuffling string s and then add one more letter at a random position.
I am to return the letter that was added to t.

Here is my solution to the problem:

```
class Solution:
    def findTheDifference(self, s: str, t: str) -> str:
        
        dict_s = {}
        dict_t = {}

        # loop through string and add the frequency into a dictionary
        for i in s:
            if i not in dict_s:
                dict_s[i] = 1
            else:
                dict_s[i] += 1

        for i in t:
            if i not in dict_t:
                dict_t[i] = 1

            else:
                dict_t[i] += 1

        # compare the frequency of both dictionaries
        for key, value in dict_t.items():
            if key not in dict_s:
                difference = key

            elif value != dict_s[key]:
                difference = key

        return difference
```

It says I've used 17.20MB and the runtime was 42MS
I know that in everyday coding and practice these numbers are kinda irrelevant but are there any glaring mal practice in my solution that could cause major memory problems in the future if I am working on a project on a grander scale?

Comment: You could use some standard library functionality to achieve this more easily but I don't see any "glaring malpractice" as you put it. Memorywise this seems fine to me.

Comment: what kind of libraries? And where can I get them?

Comment: Google `python standard library`.

Comment: Loops are generally slow in Python (especially CPython) as opposed to native language. Thus, you should try to avoid them as much as possible to improve performance. AFAIR there is a counter in the standard library. There is also a default dict which is more convenient.

Comment: Besides, you do not really need a dictionary in most case the input string will contain character in the range 0-128 (ASCII). Even if it would not be the case >99.9% of characters should be in the range 0-65K. Arrays are faster and more compact for that. A dict can be used for very rare characters outside this range. Numpy can handle that efficiently with [`np.bincount`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html). It should be at least 10x faster and take at least 10x less memory (probably even 100x I guess for both).

Answer (score 0):

You could use **one** dict instead of two. Count one string, subtract the other.

Answer (score -1):

Not necessarily the most efficient but:

```
from collections import Counter
class Solution:
    def findTheDifference(self, s: str, t: str) -> str:
        return list((Counter(t)-Counter(s)).keys())[0]
```